# Google Maps Default Styling Hides Entire Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Trying to add Google Maps to a new web page on an existing Laravel project, which is proving to be a huge pain in the backside.

https://www.beenleighrum.com.au/findme

The code is solid as it works on multiple other websites.

The issue is that by default, the  element has a position of relative:

```
style="position: relative;overflow: hidden;"
```

If I open DevTools (F12) and change the position to Static then the map shows up. Problem is that the google maps API wants it to be relative and unless I can change it, I don't see how my map is going to display properly?

Comment: You can wrap the map element in a `<div>` that has its position set to `static`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set width & height to your map container.

```
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set you width and height to your map:

```
#map {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

which means 100% viewport width and 100% viewport height. With `vw` and `vh` you don't have to deal with the container of your `#map`.